# javascript Overriding the dates in fullcalendar.js

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am from nepal and we use a different calendar. Is there any way to override the dates of fullcalendar.js and show the dates in monthly calendar  passed using json?

Comment: Maybe you can provide more information ? So what Calendar are you using then etc...?

Comment: @Creator I am using fullcalendar.js library to build a nepali date calendar. Nepali calendar. This is how it works. [nepali calendar](http://www.nepalicalendar.com)